# How to scrape next page data as i do in the first page?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have the following code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv
url = "https://coingecko.com/en"
base_url = "https://coingecko.com"
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,"html.parser")
names = [div.a.span.text for div in soup.find_all("div",attrs={"class":"coin-content center"})]
Link = [base_url+div.a["href"] for div in soup.find_all("div",attrs={"class":"coin-content center"})]
for link in Link:
    inner_page = requests.get(link)
    inner_soup = BeautifulSoup(inner_page.content,"html.parser")
    indent = inner_soup.find("div",attrs={"class":"py-2"})
    content = indent.div.next_siblings
    Allcontent = [sibling for sibling in content if sibling.string is not None]
    print(Allcontent)
```

I have successfully enter to innerpage and grabbed **all coins'** information from the first page listed coin. But there is next page as `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9` etc. How can I go to all the *next page* and do the same as previously?

Further, the output of my code contains a lot of `\n` and space. How can I fix that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to generate all the pages and requests one by one and parse using bs4

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

req = requests.get('https://www.coingecko.com/en')
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')
last_page = soup.select('ul.pagination li:nth-of-type(8) > a:nth-of-type(1)')[0]['href']
lp = last_page.split('=')[-1]
count = 0
for i in range(int(lp)):
    count+=1
    url = 'https://www.coingecko.com/en?page='+str(count)
    print(url)
    requests.get(url)#requests each page one by one till last page
    ##parse your fileds here using bs4
```

Comment: Its working fine but how can i remove those " /n" in the output? Can you pls provide me documentation of going last page of from the first page i am newbiew so need to learn how it works thank you.

Comment: .replace('\n', '')

Comment: check my code and see what i did you will understand!

Answer (score 0):

The way you have written your script has got a messy look. Try with ***[.select()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors)*** to make it concise and less prone to break. Although I could not find the further usage of `names` in your script, I kept it as it is. Here is how you can get all the available links traversing multiple pages.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import requests

url = "https://coingecko.com/en"

while True:
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text,"lxml")
    names = [item.text for item in soup.select("span.d-lg-block")]
    for link in [urljoin(url,item["href"]) for item in soup.select(".coin-content a")]:
        inner_page = requests.get(link)
        inner_soup = BeautifulSoup(inner_page.text,"lxml")
        desc = [item.get_text(strip=True) for item in inner_soup.select(".py-2 p") if item.text]
        print(desc)

    try:
        url = urljoin(url,soup.select_one(".pagination a[rel='next']")['href'])
    except TypeError:break
```

Btw, whitespaces have also been taken care of by using `.get_text(strip=True`)

Comment: It will be helpful for me if you use comments in the code,i am new biew thats why asking,don't mind.